# TypeError: Selector object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run this practice scrapy code but it's continuously giving this error.
It is giving me error of AttributeError: Selector object is not iterable error

Here is code:

```
from scrapy import Spider


class WikiSpider(Spider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States']

    def parse(self, response):
        Tabel=response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable sortable")]')[0]
        for tabel in Tabel:        
          state=tabel.xpath('.//tbody/tr/th/a/text()')[1:].extract()
          yield{
                state
            }
```

Here is the error msg:

```
2021-10-07 04:23:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-10-07 04:23:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-10-07 04:23:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-10-07 04:23:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-10-07 04:23:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States> (referer: None)
2021-10-07 04:23:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>     
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>    
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>        
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Abu Bakar Siddique\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "D:\tutorials\WEB scrapping\web scraping practice projects\wikipedia\wikipedia\spiders\wiki.py", line 17, in parse
    for tabel in Tabel:
TypeError: 'Selector' object is not iterable
```

Thanks in advance for awesome support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are missing key in yield:

```
from scrapy import Spider


class WikiSpider(Spider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States']

    def parse(self, response):
        Tabel = response.xpath(
            '//table[contains(@class,"wikitable sortable")]')
        for tabel in Tabel:
            state = tabel.xpath('.//tbody/tr/th/a/text()')[1:].extract()
            yield {
                'state': state
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you doing `Tabel=response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable sortable")]')` it give you list of Selector but you selected first element with `[0]` at end of line
that gives you a Selector because of that you get that exception

change
`Tabel=response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable sortable")]')[0]`
to
`Tabel=response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable sortable")]')`

Comment: Thanks fro replying. But after that following error comes, unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: ```yield{
    state
}```
you using list in set 
you have to return a dict and dict have keys like this
```yield{
    "data": state
}```